# Skip WHERE clause in Postgres, depending on parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to skip the `WHERE` clause if `include_self` is true:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_function(document_id text, include_self boolean defaut false) RETURNS SETOF "Hierarchies" AS $$
WITH RECURSIVE documents AS (
    SELECT "id", name, "parentId"
    FROM "public"."Hierarchies"
    WHERE "id" = document_id
  UNION ALL
    SELECT p.id, p.name, p."parentId"
    FROM "public"."Hierarchies" p
    JOIN documents ON p.id = documents."parentId"
)
SELECT id, name, "parentId" FROM documents
WHERE id != document_id; -- HERE: I need to skip this if include_self is true

$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Comment: `WHERE (id <> document_id) or include_self is false`

Comment: WHERE (include_Self OR id != document_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an OR condition with your boolean parameter

```
WHERE (NOT include_self AND id <> document_id)
   OR include_self
```